# Get data from JSON.parse from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been looking everywhere for the answer.

I have the JSON string

```
"[{"id":"0"}]"
```

I've tried

```
obj['id'] and obj.id
```

but that doesn't work

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/checkdoctorappointmentonday.php',
        data: 'doctorName=' + doctorName + '&dayOfEvent=' + date1,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (json) {
            obj = JSON.parse(json.data)[0];
            b = obj.id;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Am I missing anything?

This is the php used to get the result
**Edit:**

```
    <?php
$doctorName = $_POST['doctorName'];
$dayOfEvent = $_POST['dayOfEvent'];


// Query that retrieves events
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'id'
            FROM doctoravailability
            WHERE start >='$dayOfEvent' AND start < DATE_ADD('$dayOfEvent', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
            AND title = '$doctorName'
            AND backgroundColor = 'red'
          ";

// connection to the database
try {
    $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// Execute the query
$resultat = $bdd->query($query) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

// sending the encoded result to success page
echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

Comment: Is your PHP script sending `Content-type: application/json`? jQuery automatically parses the result if it sees this, so you don't need to parse it again.

Comment: I have added the php

Comment: have you tried  $.pareseJSON() method ?

Comment: Not sure I understood the question but to access in javascript var obj = "[{"id":"0"}]"; you would use obj[0].id  (edit: or obj[0]["id"]  )

Comment: @user2728841 He has `[0]` on the `JSON.parse` line.

Comment: @user2728841 you provided me with the correct answer. IF you want to add it as a full answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, the object is actually an array containing an object

```
var str = "[{\"id\":\"0\"}]";
var obj = JSON.parse(str)[0];
alert(obj.id);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ae0bgag/

obj["id"] would have also worked, its the same as obj.id

Answer (score 0):

Does your JSON string actually have the start and end " in it, or have you just added them there to illustrate that it is a string?

Assuming that our data string actually has the ", then you just want to use the syntax

```
[{"id":"0"}]
```

Comment: `console.log()` shows double quotes when it's logging a string.

Comment: If that is shown after you have parsed to JSON, then check the raw response from the server to see if you have the quote marks around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'php/checkdoctorappointmentonday.php',
        data: {
            doctorName: doctorName,
            dayOfEvent: date1
        },      
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            b = data.0.id;
        }
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $doctorName = $_POST['doctorName'];
    $dayOfEvent = $_POST['dayOfEvent'];


    // Query that retrieves events
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'id'
                FROM doctoravailability
                WHERE start >='$dayOfEvent' AND start < DATE_ADD('$dayOfEvent', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                AND title = '$doctorName'
                AND backgroundColor = 'red'
              ";

    // connection to the database
    try {
        $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        exit('Unable to connect to database.');
    }
    // Execute the query
    $resultat = $bdd->query($query) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

    // sending the encoded result to success page
    return $resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```